# voice recognition - matlab

Tags: voice-recognition

I have a small vouice recogntion questions. I am looking for the best and easiest way to compare voice samples (avi files). lets say I am recording 5 files saying in the first ('1') in the second ('2') and so on. later I am recording another file with ('1) and I want an algorithm that will match the two file I said ('1').
I know I can calculate the euclidean distance between the vectors, but I don't know if there is a batter algorithm to use in this case.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best soulution I found so far is to use max(conv(sample1,sampl2)). this give the maximum correlation could be obtain including phasic change. any other function will be welcomed.
ariel